# How can i draw a window content into a bitmap (using Win32 C++)

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

I need this for some animation effects and i remember there is a window message for doing this. Something like WM_PAINT but it deliveres a device context with the message.

But i can't find it anymore on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre thinking of WM_PRINT perhaps? WM_PRINT is passed an HDC in wParam.